# How can a Raspi 3B+ simply stop booting, and how can I recover it?

Tags: pi-3b+, hardware, boot-issues

I've recently run into a strange issue with my fairly new (< 1 year) Raspi 3B+: Yesterday evening it simply stopped booting! The red LED shines, and the 3.3 V and 5 V GPIO pins still supply electricity, but the monitor remains black, and the activity & keyboard LEDs don't show anything. I've tried out the following remedies to recover it, but no use:

1. All peripherals removed, including the two HATs: JustBoom sound card & S.USV UPS.
2. Network cable removed, so that only keyboard and monitor remain attached.
3. SD card removed and reinserted.
4. Tried out another power adapter.

I've also performed a visual check of my Raspi, but haven't found anything strange:

[image: recto]  [image: verso]

Does anybody know what can be the cause? Is my Raspi dead now? Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I've just tried out another SD card. I took a `dd` image of the old card and copied it onto the new one. No use: The Raspi doesn't even boot from the new card.

Comment: Possibly a corrupt SD card, have you tried another one ?

Comment: No, but I have inserted the card into my PC, and the PC was able to read it without showing sings of trouble.

Comment: Have you tried a different SD card? You seem to have tried everything but that.

Comment: I’d still recommend trying a new one. Even though your PC can read the card doesn’t mean there isn’t an issue with it booting a Pi.

Comment: Assuming your PC isn't running Linux it will only be able to read the FAT partition not the ext4 partition where the rootfs resides. There's a guide here http://www.simplyembedded.org/archives/filesystems-with-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @Bra1n It's indeed a Linux PC, and I was able to read-access both partitions.

Comment: What does the ACT LED (the green LED) do when you apply power? Have you tried to `ping` the RPi to check if the network connection is working?

Comment: if new SD card also doesn't work, try booting from USB - the 3B+ is USB boot capable out of the box - if that works, could be a (physical) problem with the sd card slot - inspect it - also, if it does boot from USB, insert an sd card and see if it's detected

Comment: @Neppomuk - if the card is readable, and there's absolutely no activity on the activity LED (the green one) - then try booting from USB - the 3B+ is USB bootable out of the box

Comment: Read the troubleshooting guide and update your question accordingly, https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Comment: @Seamus As I've already written, die ACT LED remains dark. I can't reach the RPi via network, either (it has a static IP).

Comment: Yes - I saw that, but what was not clear to me was whether or not you checked it *immediately* after applying power. The ACT LED *used to* signal some specific problems immediately after power-up, but I don't know if it still does. And [this link](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) may still be useful in troubleshooting.

Comment: The SD card can be OK but the data on it could be corrupt, as others have suggested try a new card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving quite a number of useful tips (thank you!), I found out that the Raspbian installation on my µSD card was apparently corrupt: I overwrote the existing image with a fresh image from the Raspbian server by using `dd`, plugged the card into my Pi, and suddenly it booted! I still don't know what was really wrong with the old (> 5 years) installation (it's hard to tell when the screen simply remains dark), and now I've got to perform the tedious task of installing all the stuff I used to have on the old card for the second time. :(